# can't i put <data:label.name/> to <title>HERE</title>?

Tags: html, blogger

How to show label name on browser tab? :( help me
I want to show my label to tab, any trick for it?

Tricks - ABC Tricks

```
<title><data:label.name/> - <data:blog.pageName/></title>
```

Comment: blogger brother...
is it possible to show label name on browser tab???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can display **label name** in browser tab using `<data:blog.searchLabel/>`

Example title code:

```
<title><data:blog.searchLabel/></title>
```

Comment: thank you brother... it work on label page..
but it doesn't work on post page.. hahahaha.. :D
i really want to display both label name + post title
like this : 
<title><data:blog.searchLabel/> - <data:blog.pageName/></title>
:D but if its impossible... its okay.. thanks for your help..

Comment: no no, it is possible to show both **Label Name** and **Post Title** on their respective pages, the method I mentioned above is just one the possibilities to show label name on the browser tab since that's what you asked.You can use `<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>` , it displays **Blog Title**, **Post Title**, **Label Name**, **Page Name** etc.